# How do I make an array with banned users? | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an array with banned users, but how do I do that in Discord.js v14?

I've tried

```js
const bannedUsers = await interaction.guild.bans.fetch();
const bannedUserArray = bannedUsers.map(user => user.user.username);
```

and more things like that (but they all resulted in the same error...)

The error was the following, including the places where the error happened.

```
return regex.test(input) ? Result.ok(input) : Result.err(new ExpectedConstraintError(type, "Invalid string format", input, expected));
                                                               ^

ExpectedConstraintError: Invalid string format
```

Comment: What do you get when you log the `bannedUsers` to console, before trying to map them to an array?

Comment: @FiddlingAway, it doesn't log anything, it just gives an error.

Comment: The code you present wouldn't be producing such error. Check the file name and line number of the error's stack trace

Comment: @Mart did you put the `console.log()` right after `bannedUsers` definition?

Comment: @ACGaming Yeah, it is

Comment: @Elitezen Yeah - you were actually complete right. I don't know how to close a post, but it can be closed.